# How to update one state item based on other state changes?

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, react-context, react-state

I'm using react context to manage the show/hide of some elements, since those elements depend on the return data of multiple server calls. What is the correct way to update the state of the context based on other state changes?

This is what I tried and it did not work since it becomes an infinite loop. All the `prevState` items contain either `null` or the return data from the server.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  this.setState({
    showX: (
      prevState.a &&
      prevState.b &&
      prevState.c
    ),
    showY: (
      prevState.d
    )
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call `setState` within `componentDidUpdate` only with a conditional statement that checks whether the props or state actually change. Also get a boolean value using `!!` or `Boolean constructor`

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  const { a, b, c, d } = this.props;
  if (a !== prevState.a || b !== prevState.b || c !== prevState.c || d !== prevState.d) {
    this.setState({
      showX: !!(
        prevState.a &&
        prevState.b &&
        prevState.c
      ),
      showY: !!prevState.d
    })
  }

}
```

Comment: I don't have props in the context.

Comment: Sorry for the typo, prevProps should be prevState in the answer. Updated it